# sql not returning any rows

Tags: asp.net, sql, gridview, webforms

am trying to query a table for rows that have dates between two dates. The query i am using is:-

```
addInventorySelectAll.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM AddInventory WHERE (DATE BETWEEN '"+row2Text1.Text+"' AND '"+row2TextBox2.Text+"')";
```

am using a data source in an asp.net page. The textboxes have calender extender ajax control on them which was used while adding data to the tables. So the dates are in in same mm/dd/yyyy format. The query gives no result. any idea on what am i doing wrong here ?

Comment: please put a breakpoint in the line above, after the selectcommand text has been assigned inspect the value, copy it to SQL Management studio or your other database tool and run the query. do you get any result?

Comment: the date format is not the sql standard.

Comment: Have you tried running that query in SQL Management Studio to see if it returns any results?

Comment: @DavidePiras- earlier my textboxes were not getting values, now they are. and the select query is getting the dates in mm/dd/yyyy format. still no results.

Comment: @Aristos- so what should the query be ?

Comment: @DirkDeWinnaar- tried but its giving error, the data there shows date in yyyy-mm-dd format whereas in visual studio server explorer, table data it shows mm/dd/yyyy format.

Comment: Also. while you're at it changing your code: use **parametrized queries** instead of concatenating together your SQL statements! Doing this opens the barn door to SQL injections attacks - and that's **not** something you want to have to deal with.....

Comment: @marc_s could you guide me to a resource on that ? do you mean that i should assign the row2Text1.Text to a variable and then use that in a query ?

Comment: @dunkmaster: see Jeff Atwood's excellent blog post [Give me parametrized SQL, or give me death](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html) that explains the topic in great detail

Comment: Thank you marc. I will keep this in mind for my future college projects and will surely point out the added security of my projects to my teachers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[CAST and CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

```
addInventorySelectAll.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM AddInventory 
    WHERE 
    (DATE BETWEEN CONVERT(datetime, '"+row2Text1.Text+"', 101) 
    AND CONVERT(datetime, '"+row2Text2.Text+"', 101))"
```

Comment: Thanks this worked, just missing a ) at the end. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @dunkmaster Yes, forgot the closing paren. Will update answer for others. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Try using the < and > operators instead

```
WHERE date >= '"+row2Text1.Text+"' AND date <= '"+row2TextBox2.Text+"'
```

**Update**

I just reliased your using using mm/dd/yyyy. This wont work with that format unfornuatly but will work with yyyy/mm/dd